# Why I can't catch json data from web

Tags: android, json

Like title , I tried many example code from web
But I can't success.

This is my MaiActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.bustime;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    final String url = "http://imp.5284.com.tw/TaipeiBusService/EstimateTime.aspx?DataFormat=json" ;
    private Spinner spinner ;
    private String time[];
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTime;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        new GenerateBusData().execute();
    }


    public class GenerateBusData extends AsyncTask<Void,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            try{
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                    JSONArray i = json.getJSONArray("BusInfo");
                    time=new String[i.length()];
                    System.out.println("i.length()=>"+i.length());
                    for(int x=0;x<5;x++) {

                    Object jsonOb = i.get(x);
                    JSONObject t = new JSONObject(jsonOb.toString());
                    Object jsonOb1 = t.get("EstimateTime").toString();

                    time[x] = jsonOb1.toString();
                }

            }catch(JSONException e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




//            try{
//                JSONObject j = readJsonFromUrl("http://imp.5284.com.tw/TaipeiBusService/EstimateTime.aspx?DataFormat=json");
//                JSONArray i = j.getJSONArray("BusInfo");
//                time=new String[i.length()];
//                System.out.println("i.length()=>"+i.length());
//                for(int x=0;x<10;x++){
//
//                    Object jsonOb = i.get(x);
//                    JSONObject t = new JSONObject(jsonOb.toString());
//                    Object jsonOb1 = t.get("EstimateTime").toString();
//
//                    time[x] = jsonOb1.toString();

//                }
//            }catch (Exception e){
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }


            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            String []tmp = {"a","b","c"};
            adapterTime=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,time);
            adapterTime.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapterTime);
        }
    }








    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java

```
package com.example.user.bustime;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by USER on 2015/2/1.
 */
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream iStream = null;
    static JSONObject jsonOb = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser(){}

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try{
            HttpResponse response= client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }else{
                Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file");
            }
        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            jsonOb = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSON Parser","Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        return jsonOb;
    }


}
```

And my json file like that

{"EssentialInfo":{"Location":{"name":"臺北市","CenterName":"臺北市動態資訊中心"},"UpdateTime":"2015-02-01 10:07:14","CoordinateSystem":"WGS84"},"BusInfo":[{"StopID":138730.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138731.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138732.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138733.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138734.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138735.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138736.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138737.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"-1"},{"StopID":138738.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"0"},{"StopID":138739.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"120"},{"StopID":138740.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"120"},{"StopID":138741.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"240"},{"StopID":138742.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"240"},{"StopID":138743.0,"GoBack":"0","RouteID":16588.0,"EstimateTime":"0"}]}

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please log every exceptions in try catch, and post them here.

Answer (score -1):

You should save your json data & put it onto any other public service like Dropbox, then change your code to access the file to see if that works.

If it works, your problem probably in the service provider(http://imp.5284.com.tw/TaipeiBusService/EstimateTime.aspx) not the data.

Finally, you really should post your error message here too, otherwise no one will know how to help you out.

thanks.